# SimpleInjector Factory Delegates - Create instance with dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Based on the article [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Resolve-Instances-By-Key), how does one go about creating instances that take dependencies via constructor?

E.g.

```
var container = new Container();

var factory = new RequestHandlerFactory(container);

factory.Register<DefaultRequestHandler>("default");
factory.Register<OrdersRequestHandler>("orders");
factory.Register<CustomersRequestHandler>("customers");

container.RegisterSingle<IRequestHandlerFactory>(factory);
```

Now if I were to create `OrdersRequestHandler` using some constructor injected dependencies like this:

```
public OrdersRequestHandler(string uri, IOrderValidationService) {
    // do something with deps
}
```

how would that be done?

I've tried registering the implementation with constructor arguments and then registering with the factory, but that results in an error as the factory is unable to create the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding the following method to the `RequestHandlerFactory`:

```
public void Register(string name, Func<IRequestHandler> factory) {

    var producer = Lifestyle.Transient
        .CreateProducer<IRequestHandler>(factory, container);

    this.producers.Add(name, producer);
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
factory.Register("orders", () => new OrdersRequestHandler(
    "my uri",
    container.GetInstance<IOrderValidationService>()));
```

However, if that `string uri` is used in more than one component, you might want to consider hiding that `uri` behind an abstraction. For instance:

```
public interface ISomeWebServiceClientProxy {
    Data LoadData();
}

class RealSomeWebServiceClientProxy : ISomeWebServiceClientProxy {
    private readonly string uri;
    public RealSomeWebServiceClientProxy(string uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public Data LoadData() {
        // use uri, call web service, return data.
    }
}
```

This way the `OrdersRequestHandler` can simply take a dependency on `ISomeWebServiceClientProxy` instead of the ambiguous `string`:

```
public OrdersRequestHandler(ISomeWebServiceClientProxy proxy, 
    IOrderValidationService service) {
    // store dependencies
}
```